# rails 2 read file from http post body

Tags: ruby, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using rails 2 and I am trying to read a file from http post request body.

```
  def get_file_from_request(request, file_name)
    file = Tempfile.new([File.basename(file_name, ".*"), File.extname(file_name)])
    Rails.logger.info "#{request.body.size}" # returns 130
    file.write(request.body.read)
    file
  end
```

If I do

> request.inspect

I get following:

```
...
"rack.version"=>[1, 2], "rack.input"=>#<PhusionPassenger::Utils::TeeInput:0x0000000d3a6148 @len=130, @socket=nil, @bytes_read=130, @tmp=#<StringIO:0x0000000d3a60d0>>, "rack.errors"=>#<IO:<STDERR>>, "rack.multithread"=>false, "rack.multiprocess"=>true, "rack.run_once"=>false, "rack.url_scheme"=>"http", "rack.hijack?"=>true, "rack.hijack"=>#<Proc:0x0000000d3a5ec8@/data/rbenv/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p550/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.42/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:69 (lambda)>,
...
```

Are there any obvious problems with my approach?

Can someone help me with extracting files from request body? The file is definitely not 130 bytes. Its is like 3 MB.

EDIT: Here is the controller class

```
class Api::PhotosController < Api::BaseController
  before_filter :verify_session, :except => [:new, :show_image]

  def create
    Rails.logger.info "upload photo request: params=#{params.inspect}, request=#{request.inspect}"
...
      file = get_file_from_request(request, params[:file_name])
...
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.info "Could not upload photo: params=#{params.inspect}, exception=#{e.backtrace}"
    render_error(e)
  end

private

      def get_file_from_request(request, file_name)
        file = Tempfile.new([File.basename(file_name, ".*"), File.extname(file_name)])
        Rails.logger.info "#{request.body.size}" # returns 130
        file.write(request.body.read)
        file
      end
end
```

Comment: What is calling this function?  How is `request` acquired?  Please post code that shows the origin and history of `request`.  The issue is going to be an upstream misunderstanding.

Comment: updated with more details

Comment: OK, next 2 questions: 1) at 130 bytes, what does `request.body` contain, exactly? and 2) what do the logs for the action look like?

Comment: It contains post params. such as "a=x&b=y&c=z" but not the file contents. I am posting file to the api and its not a multipart request.

Comment: What does the code look like that's posting the file?  And, can you show the (redacted) HTTP headers for the API request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 2 you may have to use `request.raw_post`. Does that help?